# SQLalchemy/wtforms update issue - 400 bad request

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

What I'm trying to do is, once the user submits all the results I want it to update the Fixture_prediction model according to my filters. Although what I get is 400 bad request. The log doesnt tell me enough to know whats going wrong. Any ideas?

I think its to do with the tuple data submitted through the form...

The form displays fine its just when I submit the form it goes straight to a bad request.

**my error**

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

**What I have currently:**

**views**

```
@app.route('/predictor/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def predictions():
    user_id = g.user.id
    # retrieve predictions
    prediction= db.session.query(Fixture_prediction,\
                Fixture_prediction.fixture_id,Fixture.stage,\
                Fixture.home_team,Fixture_prediction.home_score,\
                Fixture_prediction.away_score,Fixture.away_team)\
                .outerjoin(Fixture,Fixture.id==Fixture_prediction.fixture_id)\
                .outerjoin(User,Fixture_prediction.user_id == User.id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==Fixture.id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id).all()
    data = {'predictions': prediction}
    form = PredictionListForm(data=MultiDict(data))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('A score is missing, please fill in all predictions')
            render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
        else:
            #for pred in prediction:
            store=Fixture_prediction.query\
                            .filter_by(user_id=user_id)\
                            .filter_by(fixture_id=request.form['fixture_id'])\
                            .update({'home_score':request.form['home_score']\
                                    ,'away_score':request.form['away_score']})
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Prediction added')
            return redirect(url_for("predictions"))
    # display current predictions
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Predictions</h1>
  <p></p>
  <p>Please make your predictions here</p>
  <form action='' method='post'>
    {{form.predictions()}}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Predictions"></p>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**forms**

```
class PredictionForm(WTForm):
    fixture_id = fields.IntegerField(validators=[validators.required()])
    stage = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])
    home_team = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])
    home_score = fields.IntegerField(validators=[validators.required()])
    away_score = fields.IntegerField(validators=[validators.required()])
    away_team = fields.TextField(validators=[validators.required()])

class PredictionListForm(WTForm):
    predictions = FieldList(FormField(PredictionForm))
```

Comment: You haven't included your `@app.route` code-- are you telling it to accept post requests?  e.g. `@app.route('/eg/', methods=['post','get'])`

Comment: sorry forgot to add that here but its in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no field `fixture_id` in `request.form`.  This results in a `KeyError` being raised by the underlying MultiDict, which is translated into a 400 by Flask.

The reason there is no `fixture_id` is because you are using the field enclosures `FieldList` and `FormField` both of which alter the names you provide to WTForms to avoid collisions.

The fix is to simply use the `form` instance that you have to access the data (as WTForms has already mapped it for you):

```
# in your else clause
for prediction in form.predictions:
    store = Fixture_prediction.query \
                              .filter_by(user_id=user_id) \
                              .filter_by(fixture_id=prediction.fixture_id.data)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Where does filter_id come from? Do I need to import it?

Comment: Hang on a sec...change filter_id to fixture_id

Comment: @Lorbat - yes, that was a typo - fixed :-)

Comment: If thats the case then shouldn't this work? .update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\                                      ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})

Comment: @Lorbat - Yes, it should.

Comment: What you said above has helped me with another question :D

Comment: I'll give you that as its solved my 400 bad request issue...my next question is why does nothing submit to the database...I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: Sean any ideas with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130140/how-do-you-store-the-request-form-to-db-through-wtforms-or-error-in-sqlalchemy-u

Answer (score 0):

According to the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/), a 400 occurs when:

> What happens if the key does not exist in the form attribute? In that
>   case a special KeyError is raised. You can catch it like a standard
>   KeyError but if you don’t do that, a HTTP 400 Bad Request error page
>   is shown instead. So for many situations you don’t have to deal with
>   that problem.

It sounds like the wtform is accessing a key that is not in the multidict, raising a keyerror.  To test this, wrap the validate call with a try/except.  (I think, I'd assume this is where the keyerror occurs).  If you catch the exception, you'll have your answer.

Comment: Sorry I've got a 400 bad request but I assume its the same. My set up is a Flask, all im doing is redirect(url_for('predictions')) which should bring it back to the current view...so it might be something else?