# How do you store the request.form to db through wtforms or error in sqlalchemy update?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2, wtforms, namedtuple

This is following on from this question:
[SQLalchemy/wtforms update issue - 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24119873/550039)
I have a flask framework

**Issue**

When I submit the form the flash message comes up saying prediction added although when I query the db nothing has changed?? Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

**What am I trying to achieve**

Users are able to view their predictions making changes to current predictions. If there are no new predictions then they can submit new predictions.

**views**

```
# Predictor - User makes predictions and saves/
@app.route('/predictor/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def predictions():
    user_id = g.user.id
    # retrieve predictions
    prediction= db.session.query(Fixture_prediction,\
                Fixture_prediction.fixture_id,Fixture.stage,\
                Fixture.home_team,Fixture_prediction.home_score,\
                Fixture_prediction.away_score,Fixture.away_team)\
                .outerjoin(Fixture,Fixture.id==Fixture_prediction.fixture_id)\
                .outerjoin(User,Fixture_prediction.user_id == User.id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==Fixture.id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id).all()
    data = {'predictions': prediction}
    form = PredictionListForm(data=MultiDict(data))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('A score is missing, please fill in all predictions')
            render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
        else:
            for prediction in form.predictions:
                store=db.session.query(Fixture_prediction) \
                     .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id) \
                     .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==prediction.fixture_id.data)\
                     .update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\
                     ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Prediction added')
                return redirect(url_for('predictions'))
    # display current predictions
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
```

**thoughts**
I have a feeling the below is just submitting what was already there in the first place and not the form request...

```
.update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\
                     ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Predictions</h1>
  <p></p>
  <p>Please make your predictions here</p>
  <form action='' method='post'>
    {{form.predictions()}}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Predictions"></p>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**template - alternative**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Predictions</h1>
  <p></p>
  <p>Please make your predictions here</p>
   <form action='' method='post'>
   <table>
       {%for form in form.predictions%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{form.fixture_id.data}}</td>
            <td>{{form.stage.data}}</td>
            <td>{{form.home_team.data}}</td>
            <td>{{form.home_score(size=1)}}</td>
            <td>{{form.away_score(size=1)}}</td>
            <td>{{form.away_team.data}}</td>
        </tr>
       {%endfor%}
   </table>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Predictions"></p>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**models**

```
# Fixture prediction table
class Fixture_prediction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "fixture_prediction"
    id = db.Column('fixture_prediction_id',db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fixture_id = db.Column('fixture_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fixture.fixture_id'))
    user_id = db.Column('user_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'))
    home_score = db.Column('home_score',db.Integer)
    away_score = db.Column('away_score',db.Integer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. You are going to want to pass in `request.form` to your `PredictionListForm`:

```
form = PredictionListForm(request.form, data=MultiDict(data))
```

WTForms checks inside of `request.form` first and only if it doesn't find data in it does it fall back on the `data` keyword argument.  If you don't pass in `request.form` WTForms has no request to pull from, so it will pull data from the only source it has - the `data` param you passed it with the *old* data.

Comment: +1 I didn't realise it was that easy! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm sorry Sean but you've been so helpful I'm wondering whether you can help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24160335/550039 I know we shouldn't target individual users, but it would be very much appreciated.