# How do I correctly submit results from a wtformusing Jinja with a Python /Flask setup

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, wtforms

**What I'm trying to do**

Instead of using form.predictions() I've tried to separate it out so I can style it better, although it doesn't work when I submit the predictions apart from the first prediction..i.e doesn't update it apart from the first one.

I don't really want to write them all out hence the for loop and loop.index

**Issue**

Say if update one row of scores, it does not update the db, although I get a flash message saying I have. Strangely only row 1 works and the others dont.

**views**

```
# Predictor - User makes predictions and saves/
@app.route('/predictor/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def predictions():
    user_id = g.user.id
    # retrieve predictions
    prediction= db.session.query(Fixture_prediction,\
                Fixture_prediction.fixture_id,Fixture.stage,\
                Fixture.home_team,Fixture_prediction.home_score,\
                Fixture_prediction.away_score,Fixture.away_team)\
                .outerjoin(Fixture,Fixture.id==Fixture_prediction.fixture_id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==Fixture.id)\
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id).all()
    data = {'predictions': prediction}
    form = PredictionListForm(request.form,data=MultiDict(data))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for prediction in form.predictions:
            store=db.session.query(Fixture_prediction) \
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id) \
                .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==prediction.fixture_id.data)\
                .update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\
                ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Prediction added')
            return redirect(url_for('predictions'))
    # display current predictions
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('predictor.html', form=form)
```

**template**

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Fixture Id</th>
      <th>Stage</th>
      <th>Home Team</th>
      <th>Home Score</th>
      <th>Away Score</th>
      <th>Away Team</th>
     </tr>
     {%for prediction in form.predictions%}
     <tr>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-fixture_id" type="text" value={{prediction.fixture_id.data}}></td>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-stage" type="text" value="{{prediction.stage.data}}"></td>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-home_team" type="text" value={{prediction.home_team.data}}></td>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-home_score" type="text" value={{prediction.home_score.data}}></td>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-away_score" type="text" value={{prediction.away_score.data}}></td>
  <td><input name="predictions-{{loop.index0}}-away_team" type="text" value={{prediction.away_team.data}}></td>
 </tr>
 {%endfor%}
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Predictions"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Just FYI, you should not need to do all the work by hand - if you do `{% for prediction in form.predictions %}<tr><td>{{ prediction.fixture_id() }}</td><td>{{ prediction.stage() }}</td><td>... etc. ...</td></tr>{% endfor %}` you'll still get the layout you want without having to do quite as much work :-)

Comment: Thanks Sean I'll have a look at it later...my current issue is http://stackoverflow.com/q/24179398/550039 . Once I get my site working properly then I can go through refining the code...got too much to debug :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in this block of code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for prediction in form.predictions:
        store=db.session.query(Fixture_prediction) \
            .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id) \
            .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==prediction.fixture_id.data)\
            .update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\
            ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Prediction added')
        return redirect(url_for('predictions'))
```

The problem is after the first iteration of your for loop, you commit your changes, flash a message and *redirect*.  These three statements need to be *outside* the for loop like below:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for prediction in form.predictions:
        store=db.session.query(Fixture_prediction) \
            .filter(Fixture_prediction.user_id==user_id) \
            .filter(Fixture_prediction.fixture_id==prediction.fixture_id.data)\
            .update({'home_score':prediction.home_score.data\
            ,'away_score':prediction.away_score.data})
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Prediction added')
    return redirect(url_for('predictions'))
```

Comment: Well that may not fix your problem, but that loop *is* bugged.  Unless you only want to update the first item you return.